# Какова для вас мораль «Сказки о золотом петушке» ?

Tags: литература

Любая сказка многозначна, метафорична,  рассуждать о заключенном в ней смысле может  и ребенок,  и ученые-филологи. Стоит ли искать в сказках второй план, надо ли читать "Золотого петушка" детям?

После дискуссии об имени Дадона показалось интересным поразмышлять и о морали пушкинской сказки, которая совсем не кажется очевидной. А что  об этом думаете лично Вы?

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (мое мнение)

В РЕАЛЬНОСТИ ДАДОНА

Дадон, конечно, выглядит недальновидным человеком. Прежде всего, зачем он обращается к звездочету, можно было  подумать о более надежных и предсказуемых партнерах.  Или, по крайней мере, надо было составить нормальный договор о вознаграждении за услуги, не путаясь в оценочной стоимости (нельзя же сравнивать  коня с царской конюшни и полцарства).  Именно здесь Дадон  и совершает самый важный промах: приобретая безопасность границ как НЕКУЮ ЦЕННОСТЬ, он обещает исполнение любого желания, фактически СТАВЯ ПОД УДАР БОЛЕЕ ЗНАЧИМЫЕ ВЕЩИ  (например, благополучие семьи, государство, собственную жизнь). А этот дальнозоркий петушок-прорицатель!  С оракулами тоже лучше иметь поменьше дел, эта публика ни за что не отвечает. Достаточно вспомнить общеизвестного   Креза, царя Лидии. Собираясь воевать соседей, он посоветовался с оракулом и услышал: «Падет великое царство». А царство пало его собственное.

И образование у Дадона никакое, ведь сюжет ОБ ОТЛОЖЕННОМ ЖЕЛАНИИ широко известен. Хитрый мудрец  сначала добросовестно соблюдал договор, а потом  устроил провокацию. Формально он, конечно, предупредил Дадона об опасности, но царь -то опасностью считал только военные набеги, вот  и поплатился за все допущенные ошибки. Хотя мудреца он убил не намеренно, сильно разволновавшись, но ведь и такое развитие событий можно было предугадать: конечно же звездочет захочет забрать   у него в качестве трофея САМОЕ ЦЕННОЕ НА ТЕКУЩИЙ МОМЕНТ (девицу или еще что).

В НАШЕЙ РЕАЛЬНОСТИ (ДЛЯ ВЗРОСЛЫХ)

Сказка учит нас  не решать  текущие вопросы легким, но сомнительным  путем, так как в дальнейшем это может обернуться очень серьезными потерями. Вот, к примеру, воспитание детей. Родители ЦЕНЯТ СВОЕ ВРЕМЯ, им не хочется перепираться с малышом, и они сначала убирают за него игрушки,  затем делают за него уроки, не нагружают домашними делами. Быстрее самим сделать, чем тратить время на воспитание. А в дальнейшем  это приведет к тому, что они ВСЕ СВОЕ ВРЕМЯ потратят на решение проблем неприспособленного к жизни человека.

В НАШЕЙ РЕАЛЬНОСТИ (ДЛЯ ДЕТЕЙ)

Нельзя решать свои  проблемы волшебными  средствами, надеясь на других, не тратя собственных усилий. Вот ты списал домашку у приятеля, а на контрольной что будешь делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

София, вы о событиях прошлого рассуждаете с позиций морали европейца XXI века, поэтому делаете несколько тенденциозные выводы.

Что нам известно о Дадоне и его царстве. Дадон правит уже довольно долго (успел состариться), в молодости любил воевать с соседям, причём судя по всем довольно успешно, так у него большая территория (восемь дней пути войска до шамаханской девицы означают, что от столицы до границы владений где-то 250-300 километров) и самое крупное войско в округе (золотой петушок должен лишь оповещать о том с какой стороны набег, а с неприятелем без особых проблем справляется армия). Дадон имеет взрослых наследников, что даёт возможность дальнейшего процветания царства. Царь переживает о своих подданных, не спит ночами и плачет от того, что не всегда способен их защитить. Дадон готов, не смотря на годы, лично встать на защиту своей страны.

То есть в сказке Пушкина Дадон предстаёт перед нами сильным политиком, создавшим крепкое и сильное государство.

Звездочёты в средневековье - это главные учёные, из которых впоследствии вышли математики и астрономы. Конечно ко временам Пушкина астрология уже перестала быть частью признанных наук,  но не стоит забывать, что Александр Сергеевич был довольно суеверен, а предсказания по звёздам популярны до сих пор.

За сохранность границ Дадон готов был отдать звездочёту даже полцарства, из чего можно сделать вывод, что материальные блага интересовали царя мало. Единственное, что он не готов был отдать - это любовь, страсть, да и зачем она нужна звездочёту-скопцу? Но тот попросил именно это, за что и был убит.

Царица "не боится греха" и рада смерти звездочёта и Дадон, ослеплённый страстью это не осуждает, также как не озадачился вопросом смерти своих сыновей. Итог погибает, а царица исчезает.

**Мораль для детей**: *если обещал что-либо, то держи слово, как бы ни было горько выполнять обещанное*.

**Мораль для взрослых**: *думать надо головой, а не тем местом куда петух жаренный клюёт*. Страсть приходит и уходит, а обязанности остаются.

Comment: Вот думаю: а какие еще сказки учат нас держать слово?

Comment: Наиболее ярко "Аленький цветочек" и "Лягушка-царевна", ещё можно вспомнить "Чёрную курицу".

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо.

Comment: Простите, Яzz, но царь НЕ переживает о своих подданных....и НЕ готов, несмотря (кстати слитно пишется) на годы, лично встать на защиту своей страны, он НЕ предстаёт перед нами сильным политиком, создавшим крепкое и сильное государство.Автор называет царя  Дадона  "славным", но это не авторская оценка,  это, скорее,  лишь дань царскому титулу.  Дадон, никогда не исполнявший долга государственного, забывает,  «глядя в очи» царице, свой последний долг – долг отцовский.Сказка развенчивает веру народа в  справедливого  царя. Поэтому цензура не пропустила 
"Царствуй, лежа на боку" и "Сказка ложь"

Answer (score 1):

Мораль  для  детей:  это  сказка,  дети! ( А  в сказке  полцарства  пообещать - это  раз  плюнуть. А  чего  мелочиться - всё  равно  не  отдаст. )
Мораль  для  взрослых:  шерше  ля  фам !
Вывод:  сказочка  для  взрослых !

Comment: Мне кажется, что роль Шамаханской девицы не такая значительная - здесь важна ценность предмета. Конечно, для стареющего Дадона женская любовь желанна, но будь на его месте молодой, не слишком обеспеченный, но амбициозный правитель, прельстить его красоткой было бы сложнее, тем более вряд ли он стал бы из-за нее ссориться с волшебником.  Возможно, в качестве желанного предмета звездочет обозначил бы славу, богатство, власть. Хочется вспомнить пушкинский "Выстрел", где молодой граф вначале мало ценит свою жизнь. Поэтому Сильвио, чтобы отомстить, ждет момента, когда она будет ему очень дорога.

Comment: Как  сказать!?  Может,  молодой  Дадон  тоже  взъерепенился  бы, сыновья  вот  поубивали  друг  друга.  Да  ещё  и  царский  гонор.  Нагрешил  Дадон.  И  был  наказан  за  аморальное  поведение.  Можно, конечно,  стрелки  и  шемаханскую  царицу  перевести,  но  Дадон  и  сам  хорош:  решил,  что  ему  всё  разрешено !  Вот  и  был  приговорен  автором  к  высшей  мере.  Мораль -  Бог  всё  видит !

Comment: Можно, конечно,  представить,  что  шемаханская  царица,  как  посланница  князя  тьмы,  вызывает  массовое  умопомешательство  в  зоне  своего  влияния.  В  этом  случае  Дадон - белый  и  пушистый  -  он  жертва  обстоятельств.  И  вся  эта  история  -  козни  тёмных  сил.  Звездочёт  и  петушок  тоже  и  этих.  Не  к  лицу  Богу  использовать  петушка  в  качестве  орудия  наказания,  у  него  есть  гром  небесный  и  другие,  более  величественые,  средства.  Вывод - сказка  предупреждает  об  опасности   масонства.  Какое-то  многоморальное  произведнние  получается.  Селяви !

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже трудно определить мораль сказки. Но соглашусь с предыдущем комментарием, о том, что нужно держать слово. Дадона я никак не могу назвать недальновидным. Звездочёт, наверняка, являлся очень мудрым и честным человеком. Если бы не появилась шамаханская царица, он бы так и не потребовал вознаграждения за свою неоценимую помощь. Но это - сказочная героиня, и явно не добрая волшебница. Иначе, как объяснить слепую любовь к ней обоих сыновей, до такой степени, что готовы убить друг друга, а позже царя, увидевшего её и тут же забывшего смерть обоих сыновей. А потом загадочное исчезновение царицы...её хохот после смерти звездочета
Видимо скопец, не зря же упоминается, что он скопец (то есть мужчина уже не имеющий интереса к женщинам) хотел предупредить Дадона об опасности, исходящей от царицы, он чувствовал, что это злая чародейка, уже погубившая сыновей, и не известно, что планировавшая сделать с царством, но колдовство её было сильнее всех обещаний...

Comment: Мне тоже трудно определить мораль сказки. Но соглашусь ... =========== Соглашаться или не соглашаться надо в Комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Сюжет сказки был подсказан "Легендой об арабском звездочёте"
из сборника сказок Вашингтона Ирвинга.
Но разработан этот сюжет был в духе русского народного творчества, 
и одной из основных идей сказки стала русская народная пословица
 «долг платежом красен».
  Но самое интересное, что в конце  не только наказано зло,
но  пропадает и   царица – та самая,  из - за которой
и произошло столько несчастий.То, что царица исчезает, 
позволяет нам предположить, что царица – это своеобразное
искушение, посланное царю. Это не любовь, это даже 
не восхищение красотой, это,  скорее, стремление 
к  комфорту, удобству, это то самое царствование «лежа на боку», 
 о котором так мечтает Дадон.  Здесь зло в образе царицы 
выглядит довольно привлекательно,  но гораздо большее зло заключается, 
 по мысли автора,   в тех, кто забывает   свой долг и предает ближних, поддавшись этому искушению.
        Итак,  царь не выдерживает испытания властью, славой, 
а главное, -  испытания  покоем, комфортом.
        Таким образом, тонкая ирония, насмешка, 
 выраженная  через  использование стилистически 
разнородной лексики,  гораздо ярче,  образнее, 
чем открытое осуждение, передает авторскую оценку 
изображаемых событий, заставляет задуматься 
над  прочитанным. Не случайно заканчивается сказка словами,
 ставшими крылатыми «Сказка- ложь… »
Именно эти слова не разрешила печатать цензура, 
побоявшись возможных параллелей, сравнений. 
       В сказке поднимаются достаточно глубокие 
философские проблемы: проблема справедливого 
государственного правления и

Answer (score 0):

1. Расплата, "карма": навредил соседям, рано или поздно всё к тебе вернётся.
2. Любовь к бесплатному сыру всегда ведёт в мышеловку: не пользуйтесь ничем "волшебным" - это всё обман, мыльные пузыри, законы сохранения не обманешь.
3. Возможно, проблемы соблазна, страсти (влечения к женщине) - но это, кажется, здесь не главное.

   "Давши слово, держись...", мне кажется, тоже здесь не совсем работает (или даже совсем не работает): Звездочёт заранее знал о предстоящей коллизии, он намеренно загонял царя в ловушку. Это примерно как "*святость карточного долга*" перед карточным шулером (которую карточные шулера же и придумали).